# Fewest number of multiplications to reach x^2000

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the fewest number of multiplications required to reach $x^{2000}$ from $x$, using only previously generated powers of $x$? For example, 
$$x \rightarrow x^2 \rightarrow x^4 \rightarrow x^8\rightarrow x^{16}\rightarrow x^{32}\rightarrow x^{64}\rightarrow x^{128}\rightarrow x^{256}\rightarrow x^{512}\rightarrow \\
x^{1024}\rightarrow x^{1536}\rightarrow x^{1792}\rightarrow x^{1920}\rightarrow x^{1984}\rightarrow x^{2000},$$

uses $15$ multiplications.

Answer (score 5):

Your method with $15$ multiplications is not the most efficient way to compute $x^{2000}.$ There is a scheme with $13$ multiplications, derived from the optimal addition chain for $n=2000$, see e.g. 
http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html

```
 0            x^1
 1( 0)        x^2
 2( 1)        x^4
 3( 2, 0)     x^5
 4( 3)        x^10
 5( 4, 3)     x^15
 6( 5)        x^30
 7( 6)        x^60
 8( 7)        x^120
 9( 8, 3)     x^125
10( 9)        x^250
11(10)        x^500
12(11)        x^1000
13(12)        x^2000
```

The number $13$ is confirmed in the table from https://oeis.org/A003313.

Comment: Why do you say that iis not most efficient?  Wikipedia says it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation

Comment: @fleablood: Because $13  < 15$. And I do not see your point with the Wiki link.

Comment: The "This" indicates that your answer isn't the most efficient way (though I understand that you meant that the OP's answer isn't the most efficient way) but $13$ multiplications is indeed the most efficient way.

Comment: @kingw3: Thank you for the semantic hint, corrected.

Comment: I definitely read your answer as *your* way was not the most efficient.